# Dynamically create subprojects in scala sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to register `Project`s dynamically in sbt like this:

```scala
lazy val dirs = new File("path").listFiles().filter(_.isDirectory)

val subprojects = dirs.map { p =>
  Project(p.getName, p).settings(name := p.getName)
}

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "gen",
    libraryDependencies ++= dependencies
  )

val root2 = subprojects.foldLeft(root)((x, y) => x.aggregate(y))
```

But when executing, I am getting:

> No project 'a-sub-project' in 'file:/path'.

Seems like projects are not being registered when creating them as `Project` on this line:

```scala
val subprojects = dirs.map { p =>
  Project(p.getName, p).settings(name := p.getName)
}
```

I also tried like this:

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(subprojects:_*)
  .settings(
    name := "gen",
    libraryDependencies ++= dependencies
  )
```

I get:

> no `: _*' annotation allowed here
> (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
> .aggregate(subprojects:_*)

If I run `projects` on `sbt` none of the sub projects are listed.

Comment: Do you really have enough folders to make it work loosing all this time trying to do this instead of adding the projects manually and calling it a day?

Comment: Yes, I have like 300 xD

Comment: Did you ever managed to figure out?

Comment: Unfortunately not. At the end I switched to gradle and added there the projects dynamically

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your `subprojects` declaration with the one below it should work:

```
val subprojects = new CompositeProject {
  override def componentProjects: Seq[Project] = dirs.map { p =>
    Project(p.getName, p).settings(name := p.getName)
  }
}
```

as it should register all the sub-projects in the `CompositeProject` and allow you to aggregate them